# Why mysql odbc configuration not setup in linux?

Tags: mysql, odbc, centos6, ubuntu-16.04, freeswitch

I have two systems. my first system is ubuntu 16.04. which, work as remote.
and another is centos 6. which, run in virtually. In centos, freeswitch installed. I have to send data from freeswitch to remote system means ubuntu.
on centos, my configuration of odbc.ini as :

```
[freeswitch]
DRIVER = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
SERVER = <ipaddress>
USER = root
PASSWORD = <password>
PORT = 3306
DATABASE = freeswitch
OPTION = 67108864
```

and odbcinst.int as below:

```
[MySQL]
Description     = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage       = 1
Threading = 0
```

after setup above code.
I have to check odbc connection. for this, command fire as :

```
isql -v freeswitch
```

but, it show error as :

```
[IM004][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong driver description arise this type of error.
I have set proper driver description. wrongly, setup description mention in driver field.

Comment: could you please be very specific and provide details on how you fixed it please. How did you fix it? What steps and config did you do/change?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the line 
DRIVER = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
to
DRIVER = MySQL

Thanks.